# jQuery .delegate() and .undelegate()

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have this piece of code:

```
$('#body').delegate('a', 'click', someFunc);
```

And I use CKEditor:

```
$('#cm-comment').ckeditor();
```

The problem is that when I click a tag from CKEditor, the someFunc mustn'n be called. So i tried this:

```
$('#cke_cm-comment').undelegate('a', 'click');
```

(the id is different, because CKEditor makes its own span element) But the someFunc is still called. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Use jQuery 1.7+ and start using on/off instead.

Answer (score 2):

Add a handler for the "cm-comment" element that intercepts the `<a>` clicks and stops propagation:

```
$('#cm-comment').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

That will keep the event from bubbling out to the `<body>` (assuming that your `<body>` is the element whose id is "body").